# How to get flushleft to the page margin within enumerate environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate

How do I get the  headings to come to the page margin inside of the enumerate envirnoment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
Heading
\end{flushleft}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[10]
\begin{flushleft}
Heading
\end{flushleft}
\item \lipsum[10]
\noindent\begin{flushleft}
Heading
\end{flushleft}
\item \lipsum[10]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try for instance this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushleft}
  Heading
\end{flushleft}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[10]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{flushleft}
  Heading
\end{flushleft}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item \lipsum[10]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{flushleft}
  Heading
\end{flushleft}
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item \lipsum[10]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Note also that using `flushleft` for headings is not necessarily the best possible idea.

Comment: I missed that the enumitem had a resume option. Very useful answer.

Comment: Thanks.  (Ekhm.  You might want to consider accepting/upvoting it; this is usually more reasonable, however, after some time - a better one might show up;).)